# Executing command through bash file

Tags: shell

i want to execute mysql commands through a bash file, since am new to shell script i tried a command `mysql -uroot  -proot` which worked fine. But i want to display a table further with this script(select * from product;)
from database testDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to run a single query then try something like this

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAME -e "SQL_QUERY"
```

To run multiple SQL queries or a single multi-line SQL query, Use the 
**EOF construction.**

Example -

```
mysql -u USER -pPASSWORD <<EOF
SQL_QUERY 1
SQL_QUERY 2
SQL_QUERY N
EOF
```

There is a well writen article [here](https://www.shellhacks.com/mysql-run-query-bash-script-linux-command-line/)

Comment: thank you Zohair this helped.

Answer (score 0):

According to `man mysql`:

> You can execute SQL statements in a script file (batch file) like this:
>
> ```
>  shell> mysql db_name < script.sql > output.tab
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way

`mysql -uUSER -pPASS -hHOST -e "SELECT * FROM db.table;"`